# Permutation modules in MAGMA

Tags: magma-cas

I had a question about MAGMA: Let's say we have a permutation group $G$ acting on $\{1,2,\dots ,n\}$, and we construct the permutation module over a field $F$, by using $V:=PermutationModule(G,F);$. Then, when we pick a specific vector $v$ from $V$, I couldn't figure out how I will have a particular permutation $g$ from $G$ act on $v$. I tried $g(v)$, $g*v$, $v^g$ etc., but none of them worked, MAGMA kept giving error. Does anyone know how I should proceed here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should use $v *g$, not $g*v$ (the group acts from the right).

Comment: @Morgan Rodgers : Thank you so much, it works! I have no idea how I didn't even try it. Thanks again, it truly helped a lot.